# Gradle multi module dependencies with Continuous Integration

Tags: jenkins, android-studio, continuous-integration, android-gradle-plugin

Just starting with Android Studio/Gradle/CI, I have an Android Studio project setup with a structure resembling this:

```
┌ Project
│
├── Module "lib-core" (produces .aar)
│  
├── Module "lib-v1" (produces .aar, depends on "core-lib")
│  
├── Module "lib-v2" (produces .aar, depends on "core-lib")
│  
├── ... (potentially mode libs)
│  
└── Module "test-app" (produces .apk, depends on "lib-v1" and "lib-v2")
```

"lib-core" is used directly only from inside this project, while "lib-v1" and "lib-v2" can also be used from other projects ("test-app" is a sample project to show the usage of "lib-s") and need to be on our Maven repo as aar-s.

This project is also built with Jenkins and the artifacts go to a local Maven repo (Sonatype Nexus). This is achieved through "assembleRelease uploadArchives" tasks. As a part of the CI, the projects need to be versioned accordingly. Ideally, all lib modules (actually their artifacts) should be kept at the same version.

Now to address the issue: Let's say I've bumped the version to 1.4.2. Now, when Jenkins tries to evaluate the build scripts, it complains that "lib-core" with version 1.4.2 does not yet exist, which is true. This is the case where "lib-v1" would have the dependency to "lib-core" via 'compile "org.example:lib-core:1.4.2@aar"'

If, on the other hand, "lib-v1" declares the dependency to "lib-core" via 'compile project(":lib-core")', the produced pom.xml on the Nexus-repo (for "lib-v1") doesn't include the correct reference to "lib-core"... Unfortunately I currently don't have access to a sample but if I remember correctly the groupId is something on the line of "unresolved", "unspecified" or similar. So in that case "lib-v1" can't be used further down the pipeline (using { transitive = true } to resolve "lib-core")

Is there a way to setup the build script so the "lib-core" would be built and its artifact uploaded **before** evaluating the other modules, but without splitting this into multiple projects? Or some other way of setup which would enable building of this project both on the developer machine and the CI server?

It somehow seems I'm over-complicating things and this could be accomplished in some other (simple) way, I'm just not seeing it currently.

**EDIT**

When I declare the dependency with 'compile project(":lib-core")' I get the following in pom.xml for "lib-v1" on the Nexus repo:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>Library</groupId>
<artifactId>lib-core</artifactId>
<version>unspecified</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

artifactId is correct, but groupId is the module name, while the version is "unspecified" - so the project using "lib-v1" can't resolve the "lib-core" dependency.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think it's possible to do "built and its artifact uploaded before evaluating the other modules," due to gradle has to complete "Configuration" phrase before "Execution" phrase During "Configuration" phrase, gradle will try to evaluate all dependencies in all modules.

However, "declares the dependency to "lib-core" via 'compile project(":lib-core")'" should works for you and we have similar set-up as yours which works ok. Maybe somethings wrong with module gradle/version in your build.gradle. If you can provide more details, e.g. pom.xml and build.gradle, it will be more clear.

Could you try following in your build.gradle at Project level.

```
allprojects {
    group = 'Library'
    version = '1.4.2.'
}
```

Comment: I've edited the question to added additional info about the produced pom.xml for "lib-v1" libaray, as it looks when it ends up on the Nexus repo

Comment: how about build.gradle?

Comment: Your `allprojects` snippet lead me to the right solution. Until now I was specifying the pom version and group id only for `uploadArchives` task (pom.version and pom.groupId), which was working fine until I had `compile project` dependencies. Putting `group` and `version` in the roots of the individual modules build scripts did the job. Thanks!